# Limit of a squared function over a cyclometric function

Tags: limits, roots

I am starting with limits, and this is a problem I stumbled upon:
$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{e^{x^2}-1}}{arctan(x)}$$

This is how I proceeded:
$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{e^{x^2}-1}}{arctan(x)} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{e^{x^2}-1}}{arctan(x)} \frac{1}{\frac{x}{x}} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac   {\frac{\sqrt{e^{x^2}-1}}{x}}  {\frac{arctan(x)}{x}} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{e^{x^2}-1}}{x} $$
And this is where I got stuck. I would appreciate if someone could point me the right way as I am unsure about how to proceed. EDIT: The problem states that using derivatives is prohibited.

Comment: Put the $x$ at the denominator inside the square root  and use the notable limit!

Comment: @pawel Thank you for you answer. I did what you advised, and came up with this: 

$\sqrt{\frac{e^{x^2}-1}{x^2}}$

Still, I don't see how that helped me. Did I make an mistake?

Comment: Look at my answer! I hope it is useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\sqrt{e^{x^2}-1}}{x}=-\lim_{x\to 0^-} \sqrt{\frac{e^{x^2}-1}{x^2}}=-1$. Why? let's remember that in general $\displaystyle\lim_{f(x)\to 0}\frac{e^{f(x)}-1}{f(x)}=1$.

Now $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sqrt{e^{x^2}-1}}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \sqrt{\frac{e^{x^2}-1}{x^2}}=1$. So the limit does not exist since the two limit sides are not equal.

EDIT: be careful that the difference on sign for the two limits it is due by the fact that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, so in case $x\rightarrow 0^-$ comes out a minus sign!

Comment: Thank you, this explains almost everything. My only question would be on "Let's remember that in general...". The limit you mentioned is not obvious to me. Thank you for your time, I appreciate it

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_limits. It is very important in solving limits to know the notions of notable limit! I suggest you to inform your self on this, everything could be much easier!

Comment: Thank you for your time, I believe everything is clear now!

Comment: @ampersander You're welcome! :)